# using pandas dataframe group agg function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, multi-index

There is a dataframe, say

df

```
     Country    Continent        PopulationEst

0    Germany    Europe           8.036970e+07

1    Canada     North America    35.239865+07
...
```

I want to create a dateframe that displays the size (the number of countries in each continent), and the sum, mean, and std deviation for the estimated population of each country.

I did the following:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Continent').agg(['size', 'sum','mean','std'])
```

But the result df2 has multiple level columns like below:

```
df2.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['PopulationEst'], ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

How can I remove the `PopulationEst` from the columns, so just have `['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']` columns for the dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need add `['PopulationEst']` - `agg` uses this column for aggregation:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Continent')['PopulationEst'].agg(['size', 'sum','mean','std'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Country': ['Germany', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Canada'], 
'PopulationEst': [8, 4, 35, 50], 
 'Continent': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', 'North America']},
columns=['Country','PopulationEst','Continent'])
print (df)
   Country  PopulationEst      Continent
0  Germany              8         Europe
1  Germany              4         Europe
2   Canada             35  North America
3   Canada             50  North America

df2 = df.groupby('Continent')['PopulationEst'].agg(['size', 'sum','mean','std'])
print (df2)
               size  sum  mean        std
Continent                                
Europe            2   12   6.0   2.828427
North America     2   85  42.5  10.606602
```

---

```
df2 = df.groupby('Continent').agg(['size', 'sum','mean','std'])
print (df2)
              PopulationEst                     
                       size sum  mean        std
Continent                                       
Europe                    2  12   6.0   2.828427
North America             2  85  42.5  10.606602
```

Another solution is with [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby('Continent').agg(['size', 'sum','mean','std'])
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df2)
               size  sum  mean        std
Continent                                
Europe            2   12   6.0   2.828427
North America     2   85  42.5  10.606602
```

Comment: Thank you! the results are exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do what you need:

```
grouping = {'Continent': ['size'], 'PopEst':['sum', 'mean', 'std']}
df.groupby('Continent').agg(grouping)
```